# Angular 2 Unit testing - <component> is not a known element although declared

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I'm getting an error testing a component intended to show an error message.
The component has a banner which is not recognised by the compiler.

I use a stub instead of the normal banner component since it uses some other things independent for the test. Using the normal banner component yields the same error, though.

**error.component.html**

```
<banner-component></banner-component>
<md-card class="card">
    ...
</md-card>
```

**error.component.spec.ts**

```
//imports

describe('ErrorComponent', () => {
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<ErrorComponent>;
    let app;
    let mockRouter = {
        navigate: jasmine.createSpy('navigate')
    }; 
    let activatedRoute = {};
    let location = {

    };

    beforeEach(async(() => {

            TestBed.configureTestingModule({
                imports: [MdInputModule, MdDialogModule, RouterTestingModule, MdButtonModule, MdCardModule, MdMenuModule, MdToolbarModule, MdIconModule, MdCheckboxModule, MdInputModule, MdListModule, MdAutocompleteModule, MdSelectModule, MdTooltipModule, MdSidenavModule, MdGridListModule, MdSnackBarModule],
                declarations: [BannerStubComponent, ErrorComponent], // declare the test component
                providers: [{provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: activatedRoute}, {provide: Router, useValue: mockRouter}, {provide: Location, useValue: location}]
            })
                .compileComponents();  // compile template and css

            fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ErrorComponent);
            app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
     }));

     //tests
})
```

**bannerstub.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'banner-component',
    template: ``
})
export class BannerStubComponent {

}
```

**Output**

```
'banner-component' is not a known element:
1. If 'banner-component' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'banner-component' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("[ERROR ->]<banner-component></banner-component>
<md-card class="card">
```

So far, I have tried adding a `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA` to the NgModule as suggested by the [Angular 2 Testing Documentation](https://angular.io/guide/testing#shallow-component-tests-with-no_errors_schema), without success (yields the same error).

The Stub Component is declared correctly, I am not sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: so if you comment out the banner-component in your error component html, the error goes away ?

Comment: Thanks, that pointed me in the right direction. I fell victim of my own laziness. I copied the test code for an similar component and didn't change the name in describe, causing me to think the error was with the ErrorComponent. Ended up being a different component altogether.